# Will/Can elementaryOS support ARM?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I have been looking into some ultra-portable GNU/Linux laptops for some of my younger family members.

However, I do not yet believe I can recommend these to them if they cannot run elementary OS.

---

Will or is it already usable to run elementaryOS on SBC computers like the PineBook Pro and [BBB](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black).

Comment: There was some effort to port elementaryOS to the Odroid U3: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2s5qrd/elementaryos_on_arm/

Answer (score 1):

Elementary OS is Ubuntu 18.04 with a different desktop environment(Pantheon) and custom applications.

You can install Ubuntu Server on ARM devices and then install the Elementary/Pantheon packages via the PPA. It has ARM builds from what I can tell. If it works as easily as it does on x86 hardware it should be pretty simple, although everything takes much longer on a Pi or something with similar processing power, and it may have issues. Theoretically it's simple though.

https://ubuntu.com/download/server/arm

https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-the-pantheon-desktop-on-ubuntu/

https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages